# Completely Remove an item of submenu in NavigationDrawer on Android

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer

I used following snippet to hide **visibility** of a submenu item in a NavigationDrawer, but it just erases the text, doesn't remove the space it contained in the drawer. I want to **completely remove the item**, not just the visibility.

```
mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationViewReports);

mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(Reports_DrawerMain.this);
mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.reportsMenu).getSubMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.limitations, false);
for (int i = 0; i < mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.reportsMenu).getSubMenu().size(); i++) {
 Log.I(TAG, "Menu: " + mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.reportsMenu).getSubMenu().getItem(i));
}
mNavigationView.refreshDrawableState();
```

But when I use remove Group function it doesn't remove it self. I want to remove that item from menu in such a way that it doesn't occupy any space too.

```
mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.reportsMenu).getSubMenu().removeGroup(R.id.limitations);
```

Using Support library compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

So I just had to write another line, and it shows updated result.

```
mNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.temp);
```

Where temp is an xml having no items in it.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
</menu>
```

It might not be a correct solution, but it does the job.